# In the movie Little Fish are there any moments like these?

Tags: plot-explanation, little-fish

In the movie Little Fish ... we're shown in the final scene that both Emma and Jude have lost their memories of each other. They meet now once again for the first time.

Are there any scenes in the film that happen (in chronology) after that last scene of the film?

Another way to put the same question is - are we seeing only flashbacks throughout the film or are there any flash-forwards?